# Multiple tabs on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I'v tried to create [this w3](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_vertical_tabs) code on a page works fine. But when I want to add it more then one (f.e. two or three tabs), the tabs doesn't work. What must I change in the script if i click the first tab of the second tab section; it doesn't want to open it in the first tab section.

The second I would like to know just styling it:
if I config the css that the tabcontent would be auto height, the tabs on the left side auto adjust to it (I tried to set all of them to auto height but both side auto heighted oneself different).

The code is that:

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: inherit;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 70%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you link the w3c tutorial?

Comment: do you mean that you want to have multiple layers of tabs? tabs in a tab?

Comment: No, I would like multiple tabbed boxes on the same page. Sorry, I wasn't exact.

Comment: Here is the full w3 tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp